# Deleting phone update file

Tags: updates, ota-update

A new system update was downloading to an [asus tablet](https://www.asus.com/Tablets/ASUS_Fonepad_7_FE170CG/) but then wi-fi was turned off half-way. Where is the half-downloaded update file? I want to delete it or prevent update process somehow before turning on wi-fi again.

I think DMcient was downloading the update.

Answer (score 1):

If the update is saved to the cache partition as Bo indicates, you could reboot into Recovery mode and wipe the cache partition from there.  You can look up the key combo to get into Recovery, or if you have USB Debugging enabled and `adb` installed on your PC, you can connect the device and run `adb reboot recovery`.

Answer (score 0):

It might not end well but the folder you are looking for is /cache/fota.

Comment: But the folder `/cache/` is empty.

Comment: @user92613 do you have elevated root access?

Comment: no the tablet is not rooted.

Comment: That would cause the folders to be hidden but I went to double check since I have not gone exploring and devices are different. Yep naturally it is in different locations between nexus 4 and S6. The S6 is not rooted I doubt it's the OTA but there might be a chance. Use like FX explorer go to system then search for Fota because sometimes those apps can show folders when directly searched.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful. But I had the same problem on my hauwei p9 lite and used a "firmware finder" app to get get an update earlier. Turns out the update wasnt the right one so I went into APPS open the options on "UPDATER" app itself, and cleared all data on the app and it cancelled the update.